# How do Kruskal's and Prim's algorithms compare to each other?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

I understand that both of them are used to find minimal spanning trees, and I've seen their implementations, but I don't understand how both of them compare to each other, and how they differ in complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree in a graph is a connected acyclic subgraph. A spanning tree in a graph of order $n$ is a connected acyclic subgraph of order $n$ or equivalently a connected acyclic subgraph with $n-1$ edges.

Prim's algorithm consists of building a spanning tree by adding edges (and corresponding vertices), always keeping the **connected** and **acyclic** property, until the tree contains all vertices. The complexity of the algorithm is detailled [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity): it is $O(|E|\log |V|)$ with binary heaps, and $O(|E| + |V|\log |V|)$ (which is slightly better in general case) with Fibonacci heaps, a complicated data structure.

Kruskal's algorithm consists of building the spanning tree by adding edges always keeping the **acyclic** property, until there are $|V|-1$ edges. Its complexity is detailled [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Complexity). It is $O(|E|\log|V|)$, but if the edges can be easily sorted, you can reach $O(|E|\alpha(|V|))$ with improved union-find data structure ($\alpha(x)$ is in practice very small, that is $\leq 4$ even if $x$ is the number of particles in the universe).

Both of them are greedy algorithms, but the property you keep invariant is not the same.

Comment: Nice answer. However, the contrast seems misleading. Doesn't Prim's algorithm always keep the acyclic property as well? Aren't "until the tree contains all vertices" and "until there are ||−1 edges" exactly the same here?

Comment: Well yes, you are right about Prim (the converse would be problematic). About the "until" condition, I felt it was a bit different, since in Prim's algorithm, you add vertices to the tree you are constructing, but in Kruskal's algorithm, you start with a graph consisting of all vertices and no edges, so you only add edges (though that is maybe only my point of view).

Comment: "In Prim's algorithm, you add vertices ..." That is the point. To contrast with Kruskal's algorithm, we could describe Prim's algorithm as "building a spanning tree by adding vertices". Then "until the tree contains all vertices" sounds more smooth.

Comment: Kruskal requires sorting, so it requires $O(|E| \log |E|)$ time.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I edited the answer.